# Deploying Rails using Passenger "the page you were looking for doesn't exist"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app using Passenger. I followed this guide: http://wiki.ocssolutions.com/Deploying_a_Rails_Application_With_Passenger and got all my gems installed, but when I go to the location where my app should be, I see

```
The page you were looking for doesn't exist.
You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.
```

I realize this isn't a lot of information to go on, but I have no idea what to do at this point. Where do I begin troubleshooting this?

Edit: this is in the log

```
Started GET "/rideboard" for 173.64.211.61 at 2012-07-31 18:31:26 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/rideboard"):
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
railties (3.2.3) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `block in handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
<internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
passenger (3.0.7) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
passenger (3.0.7) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

One possible problem is that in development I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and on production the server has 1.9.2. Could that be causing it?

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rideboard::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests

  get "info/about"

  resources :rides

  get "home/index"

  root :to => "rides#index"
end
```

Comment: Are you running this on your local machine as a development environment, or as a production server in combination with NGINX or Apache?

Comment: Here's where it gets tricky. I'm trying to deploy to a shared production server. The app runs fine on my local machine...

Comment: Please show us the content of routes.rb

Comment: alright, I added in the original post

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact no route in your `routes.rb` matching the requested path `/rideboard`. However, it seems you have deployed your app locally to that subpath, so that `http://your.host/rideboard` actually requests the root path of your app.

You could try to request the actual root path of your app on your server, i.e. `http://your.server/`. It should probably display your app's home page. If you then actually want to deploy it under `/rideboard`, you have to adapt your deployment setup. With passenger, you have to use `RackBaseURI` while following [the documentation of Passenger](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri).